# How can I prevent my text from being Vertically Truncated?

Tags: itext7

With this code:

```
Paragraph parExecSummFooter = new Paragraph();
PdfFont fontAttributionAndCopyrightPhrases = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(iText.IO.Font.Constants.StandardFonts.COURIER, PdfEncodings.WINANSI, true);
parExecSummFooter.SetFont(fontAttributionAndCopyrightPhrases);
parExecSummFooter.SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
parExecSummFooter.SetFontColor(ColorConstants.BLUE);
parExecSummFooter.SetFontSize(11);
parExecSummFooter.Add("\n");
parExecSummFooter.Add("This Document Profiler Analysis ©" + currentYear.ToString() + " Idiolectable");
docProfiler.Add(parExecSummFooter);
```

I get a line of text that is vertically truncated (bottom of the text on the last line is "cut off"):

[image]

What need I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Insert another linebreak after that line, like so:

```
. . .
parExecSummFooter.Add("This Document Profiler Analysis ©" + currentYear.ToString() + " Idiolectable");
parExecSummFooter.Add("\n");
docProfiler.Add(parExecSummFooter);
```